# Twilio as a proxy for many-to-many SMS conversations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

What is the best way to proxy marketplace messaging using SMS?

**User Model:**
each conversation has `owner_id` and `renter_id`, if a message is received from one it should be proxied to the other.

**If the owner is connected to many conversations**, what is the best way to make sure the messages are directed to the proper recipient?

**Update:** 
[It looks like twilio recommends purchasing a phone number for each conversation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619529/twilio-as-a-proxy-for-one-to-many-sms-conversations)

This would require owning `N` phone numbers where `N` is greater than the conversations grouped by unique user/recipient.

For example with Airbnb data model, would need to know the owner with the largest number of unique renters... This seems like a lot of potential overhead. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This concept will definitely require multiple Twilio numbers if you want to give a friction less experience (no PINs to enter ) , but you will only ever need to have as many numbers as people who a single user can contact.
This is explained in more detail [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio) . And you only need to work out a starting number and rest can be dynamic .

Say, if you maximum number of property any owner owns is N and he rents out on all 365 days to different renters , it means the owner has   N*365  renters in their "address book", you would only ever need 365N numbers, even if you had 100,000 users. If based on historical data , you could work out maximum of N and maximum of rental days ( say M) , you have the required phone numbers = N*M . This could be the starting point and doesnt have to be a fixed constant value .

As a fail safe - add a handler to when you cross a threshold - say 90% of your number pool of N*M numbers , then use the [Twilio REST API to add numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) dynamically to this pool .

Comment: You wouldn't even need that kind of threshold, if you have 0 numbers left you can dynamically buy numbers at that point. Also, you can release numbers once the relationships between users expire.